# Android: Animation Position Resets After Complete

Tags: android

I'm using an xml defined animation to slide a view off the screen. The problem is, as soon as the animation completes it resets to its original position. I need to know how to fix this. Here's the xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
   <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="500"/></set>
```

Here's the Java that I use to call it:

```
    homeScrn = (View)findViewById(R.id.homescreen);
    slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);

    //Set Click Listeners For Menu
    btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.help, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.subpage), true);
            homeScrn.startAnimation(slideLeftOut);
        }
    });
```

So basically what happens is I inflate a view underneath one. Then I animate the view on top off to the left. As soon as it gets off screen and the animation is finished it resets its position back.

Comment: Here is the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73496792/9403953

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The animations are working as expected. Just because you animated something does not mean you actually moved it. An animation only affects drawn pixels during the animation itself, not the configuration of the widgets.

You need to add an `AnimationListener`, and in the `onAnimationEnd()` method, do something that makes your move permanent (e.g., removes the view on top from its parent, marks the view on top as having visibility `GONE`).

Comment: But what should i do if the same has to slideIn. since its not actually moved then how can i slideIn the object that i have slideOut???

Comment: Even if you do you *permeneny* move your `View` in `onAnimationEnd()` it does **flicker**. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650351/android-translateanimation-resets-after-animation

Comment: slideLeftOut.setFillAfter(true) ?

Answer (score 123):

Finally got a way to work around,the right way to do this is **`setFillAfter(true)`**,

if you want to define your animation in xml then you should do some thing like this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

you can see that i have defined **`filterAfter="true"`** in the `set` tag,if you try to define it in `translate` tag it won't work,might be a **bug** in the framework!!

and then in the Code

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);
someView.startAnimation(anim);
```

**OR**

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-90, 150, 0, 0);

animation.setFillAfter(true);

animation.setDuration(1800);

someView.startAnimation(animation);
```

then it will surely work!!

Now this is a bit tricky it seems like the view is actually move to the new position but actually the pixels of the view are moved,i.e your view is actually at its initial position but not visible,you can test it if have you some button or clickable view in your view(in my case in layout),to fix that you have to manually move your view/layout to the new position

```
public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)

new TranslateAnimation(-90, 150, 0, 0);
```

now as we can see that our animation will starts from -90 x-axis to 150 x-axis

so what we do is set

```
someView.setAnimationListener(this);
```

and in

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
   someView.layout(150, 0, someView.getWidth() + 150, someView.getHeight());
}
```

now let me explain `public void layout (int left, int top, int right, int botton)`

it moves your layout to new position first argument define the left,which we is **150**,because translate animation has animated our view to **150 x-axis**, **top is 0** because we haven't animated y-axis,now in right we have done `someView.getWidth() + 150` basically we get the width of our view and added **150** because we our left is now move to **150 x-axis** to make the view width to its originall one, and bottom is equals to the height of our view.

I hope you people now understood the concept of translating, and still you have any questions you can ask right away in comment section,i feel pleasure to help :)

**EDIT** Don't use `layout()` method as it can be called by the framework when ever view is invalidated and your changes won't presist, use `LayoutParams` to set your layout parameters according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks for explanation i am using this approach too, only problem with this approach is when animation is ended animated view flickers.

Comment: @user65721 are you moving your view to new position?? and have you tried `setFillEnabled()`??

Comment: I was doing the same @CommonsWare told but **was flickering**. setting setFillAfter(true) do the trick, Thank's man!

Answer (score 33):

I might be a bit late in replying, but I have the solution for this:

Just add `android:fillAfter="true"`
in your xml

Comment: It doesn't work for translate animation. It works only for Scale Animation.

Comment: @NicolasTyler, make sure you add `fillAfter` and `fillEnabled` to the root element in your animation xml.

Comment: as xml sequential loading animation and starting cause this problem with one animation with fillafter true works perfect

Comment: @Ads This works for my **my_scale_and_rotate_animation.xml** animation. Maybe if you add a dummy `<scale.../>` element (that doesn't actually change anything) to your **translate_only_animation.xml** animation, then adding `android:fillAfter="true"` to the parent `<set.../>` element could work for you, too?

Comment: this one works for me, I used AnimationSet with an alpha and translate animation, add these to the root element (AnimationSet) will work

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
fillAfter=true
fillEnabled=true
```

your View will'not reset to original position, but if you have some buttons or something else in your view , their position will not change.

You must use `ObjectAnimator` , it works from API 11 level . It changes View position automatic,

here is the example

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContent_container, "translationX", startX, endX);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Thanks JUL for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650351/android-translateanimation-resets-after-animation/9837296#9837296)

If your app not found `object animator`, change the API level from `Project -> properties -> Android` , than `import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;`

Regards Hayk

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this command:

```
final Animation animSlideLeft = new TranslateAnimation(0, -80, 0,-350, 0, 0, 0, 0);
animSlideLeft.setFillAfter(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I went to the same question and solved it with setting the marginLeft at OnAnimationEnd()..

`MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(this.getWidth()*position, 0,0,0);
        this.setLayoutParams(params);`

Answer (score 1):

This problem has bothered for more than a week.
And Muhammad's answer pointed me a strightforward way to solve it.

I used sever layout to implement side menus with animation.
"view.layout will not be persistent. You should use LayoutParams, which will be persistent."

Here's my solution:
(Use what kind of LayoutParameter is depended on your own parent's layout):

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
layoutParams.setMargins((int) -(screenWidth * RATE), 0,
            (int) (screenWidth - screenWidth * RATE), screenHeight);
    for(View v:views) {

        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //v.layout((int) -(screenWidth * RATE), 0, (int) (screenWidth - screenWidth * RATE), screenHeight);
        v.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**fillAfter = true** will do the job to transform view to new animation positon.

```
rotateAnimation.fillAfter = true;
```

**If anybody interested to move arrow_up & arrow_down animations for a recycle view expands/collapse behavior.**

1. Initial state: **Collapse**
2. call the method with a child visibility flag(View.VISIBLE/View.GONE).

Below is code belongs to animations.

```
fun setArrowImage(imageView: ImageView, childVisibility: Int) {

    val angleRange = if (childVisibility == View.VISIBLE) Pair(0F, 180F) else 
    Pair(100f, 0F)

    val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
        angleRange.first, angleRange.second,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
    )
    rotateAnimation.duration = 300
    rotateAnimation.fillAfter = true;

    imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **helper methods** below to easily animate your view. Then you can **animate and reset after completion** like this:

```
// Animate the view:

fly(
  view1,
  (float) 0,
  (float) 0,
  (float) 0,
  (float) 1000,
  250,
  null,
  null,
  () -> {

    // Return the view to initial position on animation end:  

    fly(
      view1,
      (float) 0,
      (float) 0,
      (float) 0,
      (float) 0,
      0);

    return null;
  });
```

Helper methods:

```
/**
 * Translation of a view.
 */
public static void fly(
  View view,
  float fromXDelta,
  float toXDelta,
  float fromYDelta,
  float toYDelta,
  int duration) {

  fly(
    view,
    fromXDelta,
    toXDelta,
    fromYDelta,
    toYDelta,
    duration,
    null,
    null,
    null);
}

/**
 * Translation of a view with handlers.
 *
 * @param view       A view to animate.
 * @param fromXDelta Amount to shift by X axis for start position.
 * @param toXDelta   Amount to shift by X axis for end position.
 * @param fromYDelta Amount to shift by Y axis for start position.
 * @param toYDelta   Amount to shift by Y axis for end position.
 * @param duration   Animation duration.
 * @param start      On animation start. Otherwise NULL.
 * @param repeat     On animation repeat. Otherwise NULL.
 * @param end        On animation end. Otherwise NULL.
 */
public static void fly(
  View view,
  float fromXDelta,
  float toXDelta,
  float fromYDelta,
  float toYDelta,
  int duration,
  Callable start,
  Callable repeat,
  Callable end) {

  Animation animation;

  animation =
    new TranslateAnimation(
      fromXDelta,
      toXDelta,
      fromYDelta,
      toYDelta);

  animation.setDuration(
    duration);

  animation.setInterpolator(
    new DecelerateInterpolator());

  animation.setFillAfter(true);

  view.startAnimation(
    animation);

  animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

      if (start != null) {
        try {

          start.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

      if (end != null) {
        try {

          end.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(
      Animation animation) {

      if (repeat != null) {
        try {

          repeat.call();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }  
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from answers worked with me; although @Muhammad Babar answer inspired me to get a solution:

He mentioned that we can layout the view to the new position upon animation end:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   someView.layout(150, 0, someView.getWidth() + 150, someView.getHeight());
}
```

Although this didn't work with me instead; I had to do that in a Handler with delayed Runnable using a delay value that is slightly less than the animation duration.

So, in my case the animation duration is 500 msec, and I used a handler on 450 mesec, so it gets triggered just before the animation ends by 50 msec.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    someView.layout(150, 0, someView.width + 150, someView.hight)
    someView.requestLayout()
    someView.forceLayout()
}, 450)
```