# Changing the position of an android view appears to change the animation pivot

Tags: android, animation, xamarin

**I'm working in Xamarin (C#) but Java solutions are fine.**

I have a custom parent view with a single child view. The parent has a fixed size and position, and the child is supposed to *expand* into view where the user taps the parent. The *expand* animation is a simple fade in and scale which should pivot around the centre of the child.

The result I'm currently seeing is that the child always begins the animation at the upper-left corner of the parent and appears to translate to the point the user tapped while scaling and fading properly. This leads me to think that somehow the animation pivot is being interfered with.

<del>How can I move the child element and ensure the animation applied to it still pivots around the local centre point, and what exactly is causing this behaviour I'm currently seeing?</del>

**Edit: I've discovered that the root cause of this is that the animation scales the x and y coordinates of the child as well as its width and height, hence when the scale is 0 the child appears at the origin of the parent element, and when the scale is 1 it appears in the correct position. My new question now is: What method can I use to position the child absolutely in the parent without it being affected by scaling?**

Thanks.

### Parent View Class

```
public class Parent: RelativeLayout
{
  private RelativeLayout _child;
  private Animation      _animation;
  private LayoutParams   _layoutParams;

  public Parent(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    : base(context, attrs)
  {
    _layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(64, 64);

    _child = new RelativeLayout(context);
    _child.LayoutParameters = _layoutParams;
    _child.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
    _child.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    this.AddView(_child);

    _animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(context, Resource.Animation.Expand);
    _animation.AnimationEnd += OnAnimationEnd;

    this.Touch += OnTouch;
  }

  private void OnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
  {
    // position the top left of the child view such that
    // the center point lies over the touch point
    var x = e.Event.GetX() - (_child.Width / 2);
    var y = e.Event.GetY() - (_child.Height / 2);
    _child.SetX(x);
    _child.SetY(y);

    _child.StartAnimation(_animation);
    _child.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  }
}
```

### Expand Animation Resource

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:duration="500" >
  <scale
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >
  </scale>
  <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73496792/9403953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this animation working, although the new approach is more of a workaround than a solution.

By creating the animation programmatically and setting the pivot absolutely within the parent I was able to ensure that the child position and pivot aligned perfectly every time:

```
private void OnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
  {
    // position the top left of the child view such that
    // the center point lies over the touch point
    var x = e.Event.GetX() - (_child.Width / 2);
    var y = e.Event.GetY() - (_child.Height / 2);
    _child.SetX(x);
    _child.SetY(y);

    // define the animation with the pivot absolutely positioned over the center of the child
    var animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.Interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    animation.Duration = 500;
    animation.AddAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0.4F, 0F));
    animation.AddAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0F, 4F, 0F, 4F,
      Dimension.Absolute, x,
      Dimension.Absolute, y));

    _child.StartAnimation(animation);
    _child.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  }
```

If there were a solution which allowed an animation resource to be used and didn't require absolute values that would be far more concise, however.