# ImageView will reset to original state after rotating?

Tags: android, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Animation Position Resets After Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882826/android-animation-position-resets-after-complete)

I'm using `RotateAnimation` to rotate an `ImageView`. The code is simple:

```
this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Animation ani = new RotateAnimation(
                0, /* from degree*/
                30, /* to degree */
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        ani.setDuration(1000);
        imageView.startAnimation(ani);
    }
});
```

You can see I want the imageView rotate 30 degree.

It works, but when rotating is done, the image go back to the original state, the same position and degree before rotating.
I want to fix ImageView at last Animation position i.e want to fix the image tilted by 30 degree.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just find an solution:

```
ani.setFillAfter(true);
```

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal way when you use animation on Android.

You can:

- start a new animation with no duration and repeat property on "infinite", and you rotate your image inside
- Put the rotation value manually at the end of the animation (but you can't do that without specific animation below Android 3.0 if I'm not wrong).