# Android : Get new position of View after animation

Tags: java, android

How can i get new position of view after animation it ?

```
if(animationCompeleted == 1)
{
    return;
}

if(animationCounter != 0)
{
    this.width = this.width + 1.f;
    this.heigh = this.heigh + 1.f;
}
final ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(this.width, this.width + 1.0f, this.heigh, this.heigh + 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f);
scale.setDuration(1000);
scale.setFillAfter(true); 
scale.setFillEnabled(true);
scale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) 
    {

        animationCompeleted = 1;
        animationCounter++;
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) 
    {
        animationCompeleted = 2;
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) 
    {
        animationCompeleted = 2;
        //I want to get new position of imageView for comparing with another view(detection going-on it)


    }
});     
imageView.startAnimation(scale);
```

I want to know when my imageView near to another view.
How can i check it ?
How can i get new X and Y or Height and Width after animation?
I'm tring to get them in onAnimationEnd , but it's static values , it's not change after animation ending  ..
Sorry for grammer

Comment: `onAnimationEnd()`: `View.getX()` & `View.getY()` does not work?

Comment: this values did not change after animation, i'm getting same values before and after animation

Comment: Wow, that is counter-intuitive. Can you compute the newX and newY before the animation starts?

Comment: i did not tried, and i don't know how should i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try getLocationOnScreen method.

```
int[] locationOnScreent = new int[2];
yourView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreent);
// locationOnScreent[0] = x
// locationOnScreent[1] = y
```

Comment: i'm getting same values before and after animation

Comment: you can try this:
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setFillBefore(false);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);

Comment: I adjusted it, you can see it on my question

Comment: sorry, didn't see that, i googled and saw an amazing answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15808679/1928342

Comment: if you've found a solution, please post you answer on the current question.

Answer (score 0):

To get dimension of a view, use `View.getLayoutParams().height` and `View.getLayoutParams().width`

To get position, to have to cast LayoutParams to MarginLayoutParams and get leftMargin/topMargin/rightMargin/bottomMargin

Comment: i'm getting same values on iew.getLayoutParams().height before and after animcation

Answer (score 0):

The main confusion here, is that you have animated a REPRESENTATION OF THE VIEW, not the view itself.
Hence, the coordinates of the view after the animation never changed.

Also, the setFillAfter(true) parameter does not interfere with the process. setFillAfter(true) still affects the REPRESENTATION OF THE VIEW only.