# Toggle button element fades but suddenly reappears after animation is finished

Tags: java, android, user-interface, alpha

I am creating a UI on an android application. When I invoke the view.startAnimation(anim). It work fades the button away as desired but as soon as the animation has concluded in interpolating the alpha from 1 -> 0, it reappears. I assume the alpha reset to its original value. I am not sure what I missed.

I am using the latest android api, and testing on a galaxy s9 physical device.

I have investigate the following pages to try solve my issue, one a youtube tutorial the other a stack Overflow answered question.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6QS6m1pYMs
[Fade In Fade Out Android Animation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java)

I have set everything up as follows,
xmls:

```xml
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/my_button_toggle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
```

The above is define inside a FrameLayout with a fragment defined before it.

```xml
set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:id="@+id/fade_out"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fillAfter="true" />
</set>
```

with the calling Java put together like this..

```java
//global
ToggleButton togglebutton;
Button button;

void hideUI(){
    fade(togglebutton);
    fade(button);
}

void fade(View view){
    Button fadingButton = (Button) view;
        Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        fadingButton.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

After starting the animation.

Like this:

```
void fade(View view){ 
    Button fadingButton = (Button) view;             
    Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out);         
    fadingButton.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation); 
    fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
}
```

Edit:

Nevermind, I see you did added it in your xml.

Have a look here:

[Android: Animation Position Resets After Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3882826/5550161)

Comment: Thanks for your response tho! It was quick.