# Change position of view after end of animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I develop a widget based on `ViewGroup` and my problem is that I need to save position of items after the end of animation. I called `setFillAfter(true)` in my animation object I created `AnimationListener` and in it's `onAnimationEnd` method call `View.layout(l,t,r,b)` to set the position after animation, because I want animation to start from new item's position next time. But in this case it looks like items are layouted twice. If I don't use `View.layout(l,t,r,b)` at the end of animation, next animation starts from previous position. Here is my code:

```
private void scrollUp() {
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        final int index = i; 
        final int newleft = child.getLeft() + mOffsetBetweenItems;
        final int newTop = child.getTop() - mOffsetBetweenItems;
        TranslateAnimation scrollUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, mOffsetBetweenItems, 0, -mOffsetBetweenItems);          
        scrollUp.setDuration(1500);
        scrollUp.setFillAfter(true);        
        scrollUp.setAnimationListener(
            new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    child.layout(newleft, newTop, newleft + child.getMeasuredWidth(), newTop + child.getMeasuredHeight() );
                }
            }
        );

        child.startAnimation(scrollUp);
    }
}
```

Please give me an advice how should I reset view's position accordingly to the end position of animation?

Comment: changing position means you want set it in BOTTOM or TOP in layout, you want like this..

Comment: not BOTTOM or TOP, but in concrete X,Y coordinates which are defined by `view.layout()` method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did it. Here is the code:

```
private void scrollUp() {
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        final int index = i; 
        final int newleft = child.getLeft() + mOffsetBetweenItems;
        final int newTop = child.getTop() - mOffsetBetweenItems;
        TranslateAnimation scrollUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, mOffsetBetweenItems, 0, -mOffsetBetweenItems);          
        scrollUp.setDuration(1500);
        scrollUp.setFillEnabled(true);        
        scrollUp.setAnimationListener(
            new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    child.layout(newleft, newTop, newleft + child.getMeasuredWidth(), newTop + child.getMeasuredHeight() );
                }
            }
        );

        child.startAnimation(scrollUp);
    }
}
```

Just removed `setFillAfter(true)` and write `setFillEnabled(true)` instead of. But in this case I don't understand the logic of `setFillEnabled()` working, because it provides behavior not like describes in documentation.

Comment: Setting the new left in onAnimationEnd fixed my issues. Thanks. In your code, at what point would mOffsetBetweenItems be set/updated?

Comment: Note: Doesn't work on Lollipop at least (guessing at some API level it was incidentally implemented as above, but doesn't work at least on Lollipop for sure)

Answer (score 20):

You must use `ObjectAnimator` , it works from API 11 level . It changes View position automatic,

here is the example

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContent_container, "translationX", startX, endX);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Thanks JUL for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650351/android-translateanimation-resets-after-animation/9837296#9837296)

If your app not found `object animator`, change the API level from `Project -> properties -> Android` , than `import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;`

Comment: It animates the view. View coordinates are not changed with Object animator.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your animation; Start by giving your view a new position and then animate from the old position to the new position.

Comment: If I give a new position firstly, it's immidiately redrawing my view in new position

Comment: Not if you call startAnimation() as soon as you have changed the position.

Comment: If I call `View.layout()` before `view.startAnimation()` it redraws my view and animation starts from new position

Comment: Ah, but there are other ways to reposition your view than calling `View.layout()`. Personally I tend to modify the LayoutParams owned by the view.

Comment: `LayoutParams` just allow you to point new width and height, but I need to point also left and top coordinates

Comment: If you have a layout like `FrameLayout`, you van use the topMargin and leftMargin values to define an offset from the top left corner.
Of course, this might not be a convenient way to animate all the time, as you'll have to compensate for the margins etc.