# Android Flicker when using Animation and onAnimationEnd Listener

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 3 ImageButtons which are animated when Filling to left, like this:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    ImageButton top;
    ImageButton left;
    ImageButton right;

    top     = meMap.get("top");
    left    = meMap.get("left");
    right   = meMap.get("right");

    goLeft =
            new TranslateAnimation(0, -(top.getLeft() - left.getLeft()), 0, -(top.getTop() - left.getTop()));

    goRight =
            new TranslateAnimation(0, -(left.getLeft() - right.getLeft()), 0, -(left.getTop() - right.getTop()));

    goTopFromRight =
            new TranslateAnimation(0, top.getLeft() - right.getLeft(), 0, top.getTop() - right.getTop());


    goRight.setAnimationListener(this);

    if (velocityX<-500)
    {
        System.out.println("aaaa "+"ScrollLeft");


        goLeft.setDuration(500);   
        goLeft.setFillAfter(true);
        goLeft.setFillAfter(true);
        top.startAnimation(goLeft);

        goRight.setDuration(500);  
        goRight.setFillAfter(true);
        goRight.setFillAfter(true);
        left.startAnimation(goRight);

        goTopFromRight.setDuration(500); 
        goTopFromRight.setFillAfter(true);
        goTopFromRight.setFillAfter(true);
        right.startAnimation(goTopFromRight);

    }
```

Now, I have an onanimationEnd listener like this:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    ImageButton top;
    ImageButton left;
    ImageButton right;

    top     = meMap.get("top");
    left    = meMap.get("left");
    right   = meMap.get("right");



    top.clearAnimation();
    left.clearAnimation();
    right.clearAnimation();


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutLeft = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,R.id.CenterTextView);
    layoutLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.CenterTextView);
    top.setLayoutParams(layoutLeft);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutRight = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutRight.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,R.id.CenterTextView);
    layoutRight.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.CenterTextView);
    left.setLayoutParams(layoutRight);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutTop = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutTop.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutTop.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    right.setLayoutParams(layoutTop);


    meMap.put("top", right);
    meMap.put("left", top);
    meMap.put("right", left);

}
```

The problem is that when I am doing the animations (except goRight), my icons are Flickering for a litle moment. I don't know how to resolve this. Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ana, I think you have already read my answers here

[Android TranslateAnimation resets after animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650351/android-translateanimation-resets-after-animation/5110580#5110580)

[android animation is not finished in onAnimationEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend/5110476#comment12328975_5110476)

I had also replied to your comment, basically in stead of doing the functionality inside the  mAnimation.setAnimationListener method, you need to create custom ImageButtons and put the functionality there

```
public Class myImageButton extends ImageButton {
@Override
    protected void onAnimationEnd() {
        super.onAnimationEnd();
        //Functionality here
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay @Soham. In fact, if I understand, I have to delate the  goRight.setAnimationListener(this); and then, I have to create 3 classes for my 3 image buttons? I am sory but I am a novice.

Comment: Yess, you absolutely correct, try creating those classes and then define the functionality inside them.

Comment: In fact, the public class myImageButton shuld be inside of my Activity? What's abaut the constructor of this class? Inside, I can't Override the onAnimationEnd().

Comment: Sorry, i can Override now the onAnimationEnd, but don't know how to use this, could you please give me an exemple with my code?

Comment: Can you please help me @Soham

Answer (score 0):

I searched for all stackoverflow posts for animation issue (flicker and sluggish).
I didnt find any perfect answer. But I have found the solution for the same, which is as below,

onStart of Animation use,

```
view_you_want_to_animate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

onEnd of Animation use,

```
view_you_want_to_animate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Now my view does not have flicker or sluggish behavior when my view is animating. 
I works well for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. To clarify is this supposed to go in onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd right?

Comment: Yes you need to override onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd methods.

Comment: Ended up using animation.setFillAfter(true) instead, which got rid of the flicker.