# Android - Updating View's Height on translationY() Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a layout that I want to expand after button click, as shown below:

[image: Expectation]

The problem is **I need to use Animation**, so I decided to use `View.animate.translationY()`. Here is my code:

```
private void showBottomThreeLines(boolean show){
    if(show)
        mShiftContainer.animate().translationY(0);
    else
        mShiftContainer.animate().translationY(-(mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3));
}
```

However, this is what I get after testing:

[image: Reality]

The **current height** is still the same as the **previous height**! The view's height is using `MATCH_PARENT`. I even tried to change it to `1000dp`, but it still has the same height. How do I update view's height during `translationY()` animation?

Comment: translate doesn't set the height ..it move the view to x,y ... scale do the work for you...use mShiftContainer.animate().scaleY(-(mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3)).setDuration(2000);

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. That's why I think I need something else... I tried the `mShiftContainer.animate().scaleY(-(mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3)).setDuration(2000);`, but the layout go up that it makes my screen blank white. I think the parameter for `scaleY()` is wrong.

Comment: try different property...such as mShiftContainer.animate().scaleYBy() or mShiftContainer.animate().y()

Comment: I don't think `scaleY()` is a good solution, as it enlarges my font size, padding, margin etc. It would just break my layout. Also I've tried `y()`, but it only updates my Y position without increasing its height.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695981/animation-in-changing-layoutparams-in-linearlayout

Comment: the answer with 14 vote...it work perfect for me

Comment: he just extend the Animation and override transformation() method..to set layoutparams with height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, I find out that **defining view height after its translation will not increase its height at all**. It appears that **the sum of the entire view's height CANNOT go exceed its parent layout's height**. Which means, if you set parent layout's height as `MATCH_PARENT` and your screen size is 960 dp, your child view's maximum height will be 960 dp, even if you define its height, e.g. `android:layout_height="1200dp"`.

Therefore, I decided to **dynamically re-size parent layout's height**, and make the footer layout's height `MATCH_PARENT`. By default, my parent layout's height is `MATCH_PARENT`, but I call below method on `onCreateView()`:

```
private void adjustParentHeight(){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mView.getLayoutParams();
    mFifthLineContainer.measure(0, 0);
    params.height = metrics.heightPixels + (mFifthLineContainer.getMeasuredHeight() * 3);
    mView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This will make my footer layout become off-screen. Then I tried to use `View.animate().translationY()`, but then **I got another problem**! There is a bug in Android animation **that causes flicker when you call** `View.setY()` **on** `onAnimationEnd()`. It seems the cause is `onAnimationEnd()` **is being called before the animation truly ends**. Below are references that I use to solve this problem:

[Android Animation Flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387711/android-animation-flicker)

[Android Flicker when using Animation and onAnimationEnd Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701613/android-flicker-when-using-animation-and-onanimationend-listener)

Therefore, I changed my `showBottomThreeLines()` method:

```
private void showBottomThreeLines(boolean show){
    if(show){
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -(mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3), 0);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(300);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mShiftContainer.setY(mShiftContainer.getY() + mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        mShiftContainer.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    } else{
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, mFifthLineContainer.getHeight() * 3, 0);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(300);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mShiftContainer.setY(mFifthLineContainer.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        mShiftContainer.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;

...


private void expandView(View summary, int height, final boolean isSearch) {
        if (isSearch) summary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        summary.measure(widthSpec, height);

        Animator animator = slideAnimator(summary.getHeight(), height, summary);
        animator.start();
    }

    private void collapseView(final View summary, int height, final boolean isSearch) {
        int finalHeight = summary.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, height, summary);
        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        summary.measure(widthSpec, height);

        Animator animator = slideAnimator(summary.getHeight(), height, summary);
        animator.start();
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    /**
     * Slide animation
     *
     * @param start   start animation from position
     * @param end     end animation to position
     * @param summary view to animate
     * @return valueAnimator
     */
    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View summary) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                //Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = summary.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());//value;
                summary.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        //Contextual action menu. Shows different options in action bar when a list item is long clicked!
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_options, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            mActionMode.finish();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried your code, but still no luck. The height got changed, but the layout Y position doesn't. Is there any part of your code that has to be modified to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Harry Can you post your xml file