# Android translate animation - permanently move View to new position using AnimationListener

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I have android translate Animation. I have an ImageView with random generated position (next1, next2). I am calling void every 3 seconds. It generates new position of the View and then make animation and move View to destination position. Translate animation has  AnimationListener implemented. When the animation finish,  I move View permanently to the new position (in OnAnimationEnd). My problem is that animation position does not correspond with setting layoutParams positions. When animation end, it makes jump to a new position, which is about 50-100 pixels far. I think the positions should be the same because I use same values (next1, next2) in both situations. Please can you show me the way to find sollution ? [image: Drawing of situation here here]

```
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams pozice_motyl = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)  pozadi_motyl.getLayoutParams();    
            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,pozice_motyl.leftMargin, Animation.ABSOLUTE, next1, Animation.ABSOLUTE, pozice_motyl.topMargin, Animation.ABSOLUTE, next2);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);

            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {




                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = (int)(next1);
                    layoutParams.topMargin = (int)(next2);
                    pozadi_motyl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            pozadi_motyl.startAnimation(anim);
```

Here is XML layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/pozadi0"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"          
    android:background="@drawable/pozadi2"
    >



<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/pozadi_motyl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/obrazek_motyl"
             android:src="@drawable/motyl"
             android:layout_width="100dip"
             android:layout_height="100dip"
                         />

   </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/obrazek_pozadi0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>



 <ImageView android:id="@+id/zaba_obrazek0"
android:src="@drawable/zaba_obrazek"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>

</RelativeLayout>   
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<cz.zaba.Spojnice  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please see my answer, its directly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593484/2606290

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70812265/4606860

Answer (score 57):

I usually prefer to work with deltas in translate animation, since it avoids a lot of confusion.

Try this out, see if it works for you:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMoveRight, 0, amountToMoveDown);
anim.setDuration(1000);

anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin += amountToMoveDown;
        params.leftMargin += amountToMoveRight;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});

view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Make sure to make `amountToMoveRight` / `amountToMoveDown` `final`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Gil. Minor correction: TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMoveRight, 0, amountToMoveDown);

Comment: This causes a flicker, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650351/android-translateanimation-resets-after-animation

Comment: no need to add listener, just use setFillAfter(true)

Comment: @Valera doing this will cause unexpected behaviour when trying to intercept touch events on the animated view

Comment: For some reason I needed to put the body of `onAnimationEnd()` in a handler. I don't know why but a `handler.post()` worked, otherwise I'd see a little jerkiness at the end of animation.

Answer (score 49):

You should rather use [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html). This animates the view to its future position and you don't need to force any layout params on the view after the animation ends. And it's rather simple.

```
myView.animate().x(50f).y(100f);

myView.animate().translateX(pixelInScreen)
```

> Note: This pixel is not relative to the view. This pixel is the pixel
>   position in the screen.

Comment: any way to set a listener?

Comment: @the_prole
mView.animate().translationY(pixelInScreen)
            .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    slideIn(binding.bottomTextContainer)
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}


            })

Answer (score 12):

**Just Do like this**

```
view.animate()
            .translationY(-((root.height - (view.height)) / 2).toFloat())
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator()).duration = 1500
```

Here, `view` is your View which is animating from its origin position. `root` is root View of your XML file.

Calculation inside `translationY` is made for moving your view to the top but keeping it inside the screen, otherwise, it will go partially outside of the screen if you keep its value 0.

Comment: any way to set a listener?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me perfectly:-

```
// slide the view from its current position to below itself
public void slideUp(final View view, final View llDomestic){

    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY",0f);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    llDomestic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    animation.start();

}

// slide the view from below itself to the current position
public void slideDown(View view,View llDomestic){
    llDomestic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY",   0f);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.start();
}
```

llDomestic : The view which you want to hide.
view: The view which you want to move down or up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way -

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100f).apply {
    duration = 2000
    start()
}
```

**Note** - view is your view where you want animation.

Answer (score 1):

### Listing down 3 ways to achieve this for future reference

```
fun translateView(viewToAnimate: View, positionX: Int) {
```

**Animate View directly**

```
        viewToAnimate.animate()
            .x(positionX)
            .setDuration(600L)
            .setInterpolator(defaultAnimationInterpolator)
            .start()
```

**Object Animator**

```
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            viewToAnimate,
            View.X,
            positionX
        ).apply {
            duration = 600
            interpolator = defaultAnimationInterpolator
        }.start()
```

**Value Animator**

```
        ValueAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate.x, positionX).apply {
            duration = 2000
            interpolator = defaultAnimationInterpolator
            addUpdateListener {
                viewToAnimate.x = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
            start()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Just add this function. And we are good to goo.. 


fun moveView(viewToMove: View, targetView: View, repeatCount: Int? = 10) {
    val viewToMovePos = IntArray(2)
    viewToMove.getLocationOnScreen(viewToMovePos)

    val targetViewPos = IntArray(2)
    targetView.getLocationOnScreen(targetViewPos)

    // Calculate the distance to move
    val moveX = targetViewPos[0] - viewToMovePos[0]
    val moveY = targetViewPos[1] - viewToMovePos[1]

    // Create a TranslateAnimation for the movement
    val animation = TranslateAnimation(0f, moveX.toFloat(), 0f, moveY.toFloat())
    animation.duration = 300 // Set the duration of the animation (in milliseconds)

    // Set animation properties (optional)
    animation.fillAfter = true
    animation.repeatCount = repeatCount ?: 10


    // Start the animation on the source view
    viewToMove.startAnimation(animation)
}
```