# How to move view permanently in Android

Tags: android, view

Say I have a view,and I want to move it upward using `setTranslationY` method.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.mView);
view.setTranslationY(-10.0f);
```

The view is indeed moved upwards,but I find it still occupies the original position.How could I move the view permanently to its final position.Also I found a similar solution but does not work.[Android translate animation - permanently move View to new position using AnimationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016674/android-translate-animation-permanently-move-view-to-new-position-using-animat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and modify the [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called NineOldAndroids  for using the Honeycomb animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0! 
(http://nineoldandroids.com)

Try this...

ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, 50f);

Only You have use the static methods in the ViewHelper class and pass the view object and the value you want to set it to.