# Move imageview smoothly

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview, touch-event

I am trying to build an app that has an imageview in it. The user can drag the imageview horizontally to some position on screen using below code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
       img.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
       newimgpos[0]=event.getX()-(viewCoords[0]-img.getX());
       img.setX(newimgpos[0]);
    }
```

Now, I want that when user lifts up his finger off the screen, the imageview be moved back to x=0. I can directly set the x coordinate of the imageview to be zero but it looks like a very abrupt change; I want the imageview to move smoothly to x =0. Can this be done? I tried using below logic:

```
for(int i= (int)newimgpos[0]; i>=0; i--){
    img.setX(i);
}
```

It moves and I can see the actual movement; still it is not smooth enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Animation here. Check the following thread for more info: [Android translate animation - permanently move View to new position using AnimationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016674/android-translate-animation-permanently-move-view-to-new-position-using-animat)

Comment: Thanks! looks like this is what I needed.

Comment: Great. Good luck with the implementation